# ProcessBuilder available via MavensMate?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, flow, mavensmate

I'm using Mavensmate IDE for my SF project and I'm trying to get the metadata for the process builder that i have created in the SF and unable to find that metadata in the mavensmate, I have selected Flow & Workflow from Metadata Subscription List

Is the Process Builder process available in Mavensmate IDE?

Here is the Screenshot of my selection:

[image]

Comment: ProcessBuilder is hidden as "Flow" in metadata api. So yes, it is available in MM. But I have no idea how to create that in MM or modify

Comment: In the MM project, I do not see the FLOW folder but I do see the Workflow folder though but could not find the PB

Comment: I'd doubt you can create/edit Processes other than through the Process Builder interface. And @kurunve is right - each Process is stored as a Flow, but you can't edit it directly as any other Visual Flow

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to update your Mavensmate setting (Mavesmate -> Settings -> Project Settings) mm_api_version to the latest. Restart Mavesmate after you update. Refresh from server and you should see the process builder metadata files now.

Not sure if it's needed but I also ran the MavensMate API (mm) update too, for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Process Builder is not shown separately anywhere(managed package or change set) while selection. Its included under Flow.

If you select Flow processes from Process builder will be included automatically.